# Sending a file path from .py to another .py

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to call a foo.py passing a filePath to bar.py

foo.py

```
for path in Path('./csvs').rglob('*.csv'):
    exec(open('bar.py').read())
    exec(open('bar2.py').read())
    exec(open('bar3.py').read())
```

bar.py

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=cols)
#rest of code
```

Is it possible?

Comment: why dont you put everything in bar.py within a function and do `from bar import fn`

Comment: I though that, but it's not an option to this project

Comment: Did you try your code? What problem did you find?

Comment: Did you read all the question?

Comment: @null92 of course I read the question. If you tried that code, you would find that all your code in the `.py` files can use the `path` variable without needing to do anything special. The code you've shown works as-is. Asking "Is it possible" is easily answered by simply running your code., hence my question -- Did you try your code? What problem did you find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `.read()`ing a file you're dealing with a *string*. So you can `.replace()` a placeholder.

file1.py:

```py
exec(open("file2.py").read().replace("*place_holder*", "10"))
```

file2.py:

```py
def fn():
    print("My number is *place_holder*")
fn()
```

But be careful about what you choose as the placeholder. `.replace()` will replace all the occurrences.

Of course for more complex replacing you can use regex. It can restrict the search better and safer.

Comment: for path in Path('./csvs').rglob('*.csv'):
    exec(open('bar.py').read().replace("*path*", str(path)))

Comment: @null92 what about replacing `pd.read_csv(path`, if you don't want to touch the files? build the `(path` part and pass it to `.replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the exact format of your bar.py, but you can try:

```py
for filePath in Path('./csvs').rglob('*.csv'):
    for i in range(1, 4):
        with open(f`bar{i}.py`) as f;
            bar_py_str = f.read()

        bar_py_str = bar_py_str.replace(
            'df = pd.read_csv(filePath, usecols=cols)',
            f'df = pd.read_csv({str(filePath.resolve()}, usecols=cols)'
        )

        exec(bar_py_str)
```